# Reading a cookie with jquery that was set by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in PHP, and then have my JavaScript/jQuery read it. As I've been trying to research the issue I've seen some people talk about server side vs. client side cookies, and other people saying cookies are just cookies and there's no difference. What I do know is that PHP sees the cookies, and JavaScript doesn't.

Here's a simplified version of the PHP file that builds the page and sets the cookies.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    setcookie("card", "", time()+900, '/');
?>
<html>
<body>
       <?php 
            $card = "a string I want in my cookie";
            $_COOKIE['card'] = $card;

            foreach($_COOKIE as $c => $c_value)
            {
                echo "Cookie named " . $c . " has value " . $c_value . "<br/>";
            }
        ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.cookie@1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will correctly show the name and value of the cookie on my page. So I know I'm setting something.

But when my JavaScript runs, I don't seem to have any cookies. I tried a couple different ways to get to the value of either all cookies, or just a single target part of the cookie:

```
var all_cookies = document.cookie;
var aCard = $.cookie('card');
```

all_cookies shows up with a value of "" when I debug, and aCard just stays undefined.

So do I need to set the cookies differently with PHP? Or read them differently with either JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Check the request for the page and see if it has the header "HttpOnly" on it.

Comment: Both server side and client side technology  can read a cookie except the cookies were marked as httponly.  Perhaps you have some settings which makes cookies httponly e.g `php_flag session.cookie_httponly on` in `.htaccess`

Comment: Your are setting an empty value with setcookie. Assigning to the super global $_COOKIE has no effect on the client. In fact, assigning *any* super global should never be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `setcookie()` function sets an HTTP response header that instructs the browser to set the cookie. This is only possible if you haven't sent any output yet. Calling `setcookie()` **after** you have already output the `<!DOCTYPE` means you should be getting a "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" warning.

To set a cookie and make it available to Javascript, you need to set it at the very beginning of your script before generating any output:

```
<?php
    $card = "a string I want in my cookie";
    setcookie("card", $card, time()+900, '/');

    // note from the manual (https://php.net/setcookie):
    //     Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed
    //     on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //
    // so the "card" cookie won't be in $_COOKIE until
    // the next page load. If you want it in there
    // immediately, you need to set it manually:

    $_COOKIE['card'] = $card;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
       <?php 
            foreach($_COOKIE as $c => $c_value)
            {
                echo "Cookie named " . $c . " has value " . $c_value . "<br/>";
            }
        ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.cookie@1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now that you've used `setcookie()` before generating any output, the cookie is set properly and Javascript should be able to access it from `document.cookie` without any trouble.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful in that I may not be able to do what I want. Declaring the value of the cookie at the top of the page does allow JavaScript to pick it up (however it only has to be above the <html> tag not the <!DOCTYPE html> tag). Unfortunately what I was trying to do requires the value of the cookie to be set later on, so I may need to try another approach, since that doesn't seem to be doable.